# zip file not really getting deleted with 'PHP unlink'

Tags: php, paypal, unlink

ok, so this is my first post, and it's a bit of a tough nut.  i came up empty searching the internet.  i'm trying to create a zip file on our server that will vary in size based upon hard-set limits of our friend, paypal.  once the first archive is written, closed, and downloaded, we delete all the component files and the zip itself.  the problem arises when trying to create a new zip file with the same name.  it's like the deleted one is still there....but it's not.  it doesn't appear in cPanel's file manager because it has been allegedly deleted, but it sure as hell downloads.  note that all component files seemingly get compressed into the re-used zip because i see it happening with my echo/debug statements, but when we download it and look inside, it has 'leftovers' from the previous zip.  only when we choose a name that has never been used before for the zip archive does everything work properly.  flush() after unlink() seemed to have no effect.  not that it matters, but tested with chrome and edge.

zip  is created as follows:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('payouts.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
  echo 'cannot open <$payouts.zip>';
  exit("cannot open <$payouts.zip>\n");
}
```

added to:

```
$zip->addFile('payouts_'.$zip_file_counter.'.txt');
```

and later closed:

```
$zip->close();
```

once we 'log out' all payout* files are unlinked.

if 'payouts.zip' is changed to 'payouts[X].zip' where 'X's is some number, all works swimmingly--every single time--as mentioned above.  what can i do to fix this?  and of course, if there are any remnants on the server, how do i clean them up, short of submitting a help ticket?  btw, i have noticed that waiting a period of time seems to clear the problem.  thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**  sure enough, the files are on my server, i just can't see them.  i know this because i just zipped my site as part of a backup and wound up with a big, honkin' zip file.  any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Give me some CACHE and I will take a guess

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure, but how to handle that on the server...

Comment: No the clue was in the spelling of the word cache

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, siteground (and perhaps others) have something called "super cacher", which is turned 'on' by default.  Once I asked them to turn it off, many problems went away in addition to this one.